# Trying to find out brand of frame

Tags: identify-this-bike

Bought a frame for a new build having trouble finding out maker.

The serial number is Snacb14e01933 located underneath bottom bracket.

Any info would be appreciated

[image]

Comment: Without photos, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: Even with photos...  still impossible to tell.

Comment: Is there any data base to search serial numbers

Comment: For stolen and registered bicycles: Bikeindex.org

Comment: Not for most brands.  Unless it's a very high end French or Italian brand, or a more than $2,000 American made brand, there usually isn't info available just by serial #.  And from that pic, I'm not seeing any identifying marks that are unique to a brand.

Comment: @RoboKaren good call, I always forget about that...

Comment: The kickstand is incredibly unusual on a BMX.  Threadless steerers are relatively modern, as opposed to the traditional BMX quill stem.  Might have horizonatal dropouts at the rear - kinda hard to see with that photo.   Its very odd to have the chain still there, when someone's gone to the effort to remove other running gear.   It might be more of a rigid MTB than a BMX?  Again its hard to see sizing with the angle of the photo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looks like a lower-end, Department Store-quality BMX bike of indeterminate age and brand.  It's probably been repainted, doesn't have a head badge or any stickers, I just don't see any way to identify it at all.  I know it's a low end one because of the stamped kickstand mounting plate, any nicer bike wouldn't have that.  I would go ahead and build it anyways if you like the frame, and ride it well.

Comment: It's original paint or extremely well] painted and it is super lightweight I figured wasn't nothing to great but I only paid 5 bucks for it I just enjoy building bikes just finished my first one from a pile of broke bikes and it rides great

Comment: @Kratosofnevada  All bikes feel lightweight without their wheels.   Since you enjoy it, that's all that matters.

Answer (score -1):

Its a cheap Wlmart or Fred Myer bike. The kickstand mount is flat and welded to the frame poorly. My guess is a low range Huffy with a middle upperclass fork, all painted terribly.

Comment: I can't see the weld you're talking about. Isn't the kick-stand actually bolted to the plate visible between the chain stays?

Answer (score -1):

The serial number format is the Pacific Cycle group of brand names.

Mongoose is the most likely brand of BMX from Pacific Cycle.